# How to split schema on GraphQL Java

Tags: java, spring, graphql

I am developing a API GraphQL for a site news. But i meet a problem, i own a schema which has several mutation, query and type. I would like to split the schema in several schemas specific to their type.

Is that possible?

Answer (score -2):

```
const countryType = `
type Country {
  _id: ID!
  name: String!
  region: [Region!]!
}
`

const regionType = `
type Region {
  _id: ID!
  name: String!
  countries: [Country!]
}
`

const schema = `
${countryType}
${regionType}

# ... more stuff ...
`

module.exports = buildSchema(schema);
```

Comment: Please explain your code and how it solves the problem with some text.

Comment: Lets say Country and Region share relations in the database where country type requires a region. So this whole file would be a `country.js` by embedding parts of the schema as strings. You can take a look at Apollo's blog - they show a way to modularize the schema: [link](https://blog.apollographql.com/modularizing-your-graphql-schema-code-d7f71d5ed5f2)

Comment: You should add the explanation to the body of your answer.  There is an edit feature there for you.